# How to get the content of console log of jenkins build in email body?

Tags: jenkins, console.log, email-ext

I am running a scan on docker images using a whitesource scanner through Jenkins. I want to take the portion of build log and send it in an email. I am searching for specific keywords like the 'Project name:' and sending it via email-ext in Jenkins. But i am unable to do it with ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^Project name:", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}. It just shows a blank output in email.

Code:

```
stage('Send Email') { 
   emailext body: '''Hi, Please find below. ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^Project name:", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true} Regards, DT ''', 
   subject: 'Test - Build ${BUILD_STATUS} - Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}', to: 'justin.xavier@abcd.com' 
}
```

1. I have tried this ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^Project name:", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}, but the result is empty.
2. I tried with ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=99, escapeHtml=false}, but it shows all the log content in the email.
3. Unable to append the log to a file. ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=99, escapeHtml=false} > log.txt

This is the jenkins log.

```rb
Started by user 
[Pipeline] node
Running on DevNode in /home/cyberadmin/workspace/Whitesource/Apps/geoshield_images/geoshield-dataconnector
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /home/cyberadmin/workspace/Whitesource/Apps/geoshield_images/geoshield-dataconnector
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (WorkSpace CleanUp)
[Pipeline] cleanWs
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /home/cyberadmin/workspace/Whitesource/Apps/geoshield_images/geoshield-dataconnector
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[geoshield-dataconnector] Running shell script

Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] sh
[geoshield-dataconnector] Running shell script
+ sudo docker pull registry.abcd/dataconnector:V.1.0.0.0
V.1.0.0.0: Pulling from dataconnector
e7c96db7181b: Already exists
584a4cfc5c76: Pulling fs layer
ec4c1f08eb03: Pulling fs layer
73021472167d: Pulling fs layer
a86ac7fa4ae3: Pulling fs layer
28d2d93bdc6e: Pulling fs layer
a8ff63a747fc: Pulling fs layer
c9fd118fb9fc: Pulling fs layer
a86ac7fa4ae3: Waiting
28d2d93bdc6e: Waiting
a8ff63a747fc: Waiting
c9fd118fb9fc: Waiting
584a4cfc5c76: Verifying Checksum
584a4cfc5c76: Download complete
a86ac7fa4ae3: Verifying Checksum
a86ac7fa4ae3: Download complete
73021472167d: Verifying Checksum
73021472167d: Download complete
28d2d93bdc6e: Verifying Checksum
28d2d93bdc6e: Download complete
c9fd118fb9fc: Verifying Checksum
c9fd118fb9fc: Download complete
a8ff63a747fc: Verifying Checksum
a8ff63a747fc: Download complete
584a4cfc5c76: Pull complete
ec4c1f08eb03: Verifying Checksum
ec4c1f08eb03: Download complete
ec4c1f08eb03: Pull complete
73021472167d: Pull complete
a86ac7fa4ae3: Pull complete
28d2d93bdc6e: Pull complete
a8ff63a747fc: Pull complete
c9fd118fb9fc: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:cf62e8ba5a8a499b4a0e421a861511f7485304842ecac7de59d5a463fdab18e5
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.abcd/dataconnector:V.1.0.0.0
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Fabric OSS scanning)
Running in /home/cyberadmin/workspace/scanner/geoshield-oss
[Pipeline] dir
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
+ sudo chmod 755 wss-unified-agent-19.7.2.jar
[Pipeline] sh
[geoshield-oss] Running shell script
+ java -jar wss-unified-agent-19.7.2.jar -c dataconnector-image.config -d /opt/Whitesource/Apps/geoshield_images/geoshield-dataconnector -product Fabric -project engine-14
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:58,361 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Start: Fetch Configuration ------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:58,409 +0530] - UnifiedAgent version (pluginVersion) : 19.7.2
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:58,438 +0530] - UA Configuration {
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_PROCESS_MINUTES=15
failErrorLevel=DEFAULT
projectPerFolder=false
connectionTimeOut=60
checkPolicies=true
serviceUrl=https://app-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/agent
forceCheckAllDependencies=true
forceUpdate=true
forceUpdateFailBuildOnPolicyViolation=false
updateTypeValue=OVERRIDE
enableImpactAnalysis=false
updateInventory=true
generateScanReport=false
scanReportTimeoutMinutes=10
analyzeFrameworks=false
analyzeFrameworkReference=analyzeFrameworks.txt
updateEmptyProject=true
euaOffline=
euaDep=euaDep.json
euaVul=euaVul.json
euaRes=euaRes.json
offline=false
zip=false
prettyJson=true
resolveAllDependencies=false
ignoreSourceFiles=false
appPath=null
cargoResolveDependencies=false
cargoRunPreStep=false
cargoIgnoreSourceFiles=true
npm: {npmRunPreStep=false, npmIgnoreScripts=false, npmResolveDependencies=false, npmIncludeDevDependencies=false, npmTimeoutDependenciesCollector=60, npmIgnoreNpmLsErrors=false, npmYarnProject=false, npmYarnFrozenLockfile=false, npmIgnoreSourceFiles=true, npmIdentifyByNameAndVersion=false, npmResolveMainPackageJsonOnly=false, npmProjectNameFromDependencyFile=false, npmRemoveDuplicateDependencies=true, npmResolveAdditionalDependencies=false}
bower: {bowerResolveDependencies=false, bowerRunPreStep=false, bowerIgnoreSourceFiles=false}
nuget: {nugetResolveDependencies=false, nugetRestoreDependencies=false, nugetRunPreStep=false, nugetIgnoreSourceFiles=true, nugetResolvePackagesConfigFiles=true, nugetResolveCsProjFiles=true, nugetResolveNuspecFiles=true, nugetPreferredEnvironment=, nugetPackagesDirectory=}
ant: {antResolveDependencies=false, antPathidIncludes=, antExternalParameters=}
maven: {mavenResolveDependencies=false, mavenIgnoredScopes=, mavenAggregateModules=false, mavenIgnorePomModules=true, mavenIgnoreSourceFiles=true, mavenRunPreStep=false, mavenIgnoreDependencyTreeErrors=false, mavenEnvironmentPath=, mavenM2Path=, mavenDownloadMissingDependencies=true, mavenAdditionalArguments=}
python: {pythonResolveDependencies=false, pipPath=pip, pythonPath=python, pythonIgnorePipInstallErrors=false, pythonInstallVirtualenv=false, pythonResolveHierarchyTree=true, pythonRequirementsFileIncludes=requirements.txt,Pipfile, pythonResolveSetupPyFiles=false, pythonIgnoreSourceFiles=true, ignorePipEnvInstallErrors=false, pipenvInstallDevDependencies=false, pythonIndexUrl=, runPipenvPreStep=false, pythonIsWssPluginInstalled=false, pythonUninstallWssPlugin=false}
gradle: {gradleResolveDependencies=false, gradleRunAssembleCommand=true, gradleAggregateModules=false, gradlePreferredEnvironment=gradle, gradleLocalRepositoryPath=, gradleAdditionalArguments=, gradleIncludeScopes=, gradleBuildFileIncludes=, gradleIgnoreSourceFiles=false, gradleRunPreStep=false, gradleIgnoredScopes=, gradleDownloadMissingDependencies=true, gradleWrapperPath=}
paket: {paketResolveDependencies=false, paketIgnoredScopes=, paketRunPreStep=false, paketPath=, paketIgnoreSourceFiles=true}
go: {goResolveDependencies=false, goDependencyManager=, goCollectDependenciesAtRuntime=false, goGlideIgnoreTestPackages=true, goIgnoreSourceFiles=false, goGradleEnableTaskAlias=false}
ruby: {rubyResolveDependencies=false, rubyRunBundleInstall=false, rubyOverwriteGemFile=false, rubyInstallMissingGems=false, rubyIgnoreSourceFiles=true}
php: {phpResolveDependencies=false, phpRunPreStep=false, phpIncludeDevDependencies=false}
sbt: {sbtResolveDependencies=false, sbtAggregateModules=false, sbtRunPreStep=false, sbtTargetFolder=, sbtIgnoreSourceFiles=false}
html: {htmlResolveDependencies=false}
cocoapods: {cocoapodsResolveDependencies=false, cocoapodsRunPreStep=false, cocoapodsIgnoreSourceFiles=true}
hex: {hexResolveDependencies=false, hexRunPreStep=false, hexAggregateModules=false, hexIgnoreSourceFiles=true}
r: {rResolveDependencies=false, rRunPreStep=false, rIgnoreSourceFiles=true, rCranMirrorUrl=}
bazel: {bazelResolveDependencies=false, bazelRunPreStep=false}
imageNames=
imageTags=
imageDigests=
forceDelete=false
remoteDockerEnabled=false
maxScanImages=0
forcePull=false
maxPullImages=10
loginSudo=true
defaultamazonRegistryIds=
remoteDockerAmazonEnabled=false
amazonRegion=east
amazonMaxPullImages=0
remoteDockerAzureEnabled=false
azureUserName=
azureUserPassword=
azureRegistryNames=
remoteDockerArtifactoryEnabled=false
dockerArtifactoryUrl=
dockerArtifactoryUserName=
dockerArtifactoryUserPassword=
dockerArtifactoryRepositoryNames=
dockerArtifactoryDockerAccessMethod=
remoteDockerGoogleContainerEnabled=false
googleRepositoryNames=
googleActiveAccount=
remoteDockerHubEnabled=false
dockerHubUserName=
dockerHubUserPassword=
dockerHubOrganizationsNames=
dockerHubAccessToken=
serverlessConfiguration=
fileListPath=
dependencyDirs=Whitesource/Apps/geoshield_images/geoshield-dataconnector
configFilePath=dataconnector-image.config
includes=**/*.jar,**/*.js,**/*.ts,**/*.deb,**/*.tgz,**/*.py,**/*.dll,**/*.apk
excludes=**/*sources.jar,**/*javadoc.jar,**/*pom.xml,**/*build.gradle
dockerIncludes=.*dataconnector.*
dockerExcludes=
dockerContainerIncludes=.*.*
dockerContainerExcludes=
pythonRequirementsFileIncludes=requirements.txt
archiveExtractionDepth=7
archiveIncludes=**/*.jar
archiveExcludes=
followSymbolicLinks=true
globCaseSensitive=false
projectPerFolderIncludes=*
projectPerFolderExcludes=
failErrorLevel=DEFAULT
excludeDependenciesFromNodes=
enableGenerateProjectDetailsJson=false
artifactoryUrl=
artifactoryRepoKeys=
apiToken=******
userKey=
projectVersion=
projectToken=
projectPerSubFolder=false
requesterEmail=
productToken=
productName=Fabric
productVersion=
projectName=unityengine-14
scanComment=
requireKnownSha1=true
scanReportFileNameFormat=project_with_timestamp
artifactoryEnableScan=false
scanPackageManager=false
scanDockerImages=true
scanDockerContainers=false
scanServerlessFunctions=false
logLevel=info
logFilesLevel=DEBUG
logFilesMaxFileSize=10
logFilesMaxFilesCount=3
}
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:58,438 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- End: Fetch Configuration --------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:58,450 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Start: Docker Resolver Scan -----------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:59,277 +0530] - Filtering docker list by includes and excludes lists
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:59,285 +0530] - Handle 1 docker entities
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:37:59,285 +0530] - Image 1 of 1
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:04,628 +0530] - Extracting file /tmp/WhiteSource-Docker_dad7200b-b049-4839-bd89-216ebb37f222/registry.abcd-dataconnector.tar - Size 185261568 Bytes (176 MBs)- Free Space 31528574976 Bytes (30067 MBs)
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,566 +0530] - Found 50 system packages in image 'registry.abcd/dataconnector'
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,577 +0530] - Starting Archive Extraction (may take a few minutes)
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,849 +0530] - Starting analysis
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,849 +0530] - Scanning directories [/tmp/WhiteSource-Docker_dad7200b-b049-4839-bd89-216ebb37f222/registry.abcd-dataconnector] for package dependencies (may take a few minutes)
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,849 +0530] - Included file types: **/*.jar,**/*.js,**/*.ts,**/*.deb,**/*.tgz,**/*.py,**/*.dll,**/*.apk
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,849 +0530] - Excluded file types: **/*sources.jar,**/*javadoc.jar,**/*pom.xml,**/*build.gradle
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,849 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Start: Scan Files Matching Includes Pattern -------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:06,949 +0530] - Scanning directories [/tmp/WhiteSource-Docker_dad7200b-b049-4839-bd89-216ebb37f222/registry.abcd/dataconnector] for matching source/binary file types (may take a few minutes)
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:07,376 +0530] - Total files found according to the includes/excludes pattern: 399
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- End: Scan Files Matching Includes Pattern ---------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,197 +0530] - Finished analyzing Files
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,365 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- End: Docker Resolver Scan -------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,374 +0530] - Initializing WhiteSource Client
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,376 +0530] - Service URL is https://app-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/agent
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,430 +0530] - UpdateType set to OVERRIDE 
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,433 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Start: Check Policies -----------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:12,433 +0530] - Checking policies
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:19,225 +0530] - Some dependencies violate open source policies, however all were force updated to organization inventory.
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:20,161 +0530] - Check Policies Support Token: 399b1607baf0b46d5ab370883736896d01569830894289
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:20,404 +0530] - Policies report generated successfully
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:20,404 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- End: Check Policies -------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:20,404 +0530] - Sending Update
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:20,405 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Start: Update Inventory ---------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,556 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- End: Update Inventory -----------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,556 +0530] - 
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,556 +0530] - No new projects found.
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,556 +0530] - Updated projects:
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,556 +0530] - # registry.abcd/dataconnector V.1.0.0.0 (7afaac1a588a)
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,557 +0530] - Project name: registry.abcd/dataconnector V.1.0.0.0 (7afaac1a588a), URL: https://app-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/Wss/WSS.html#!project;id=295252
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,557 +0530] - Support Token: 2c5caed97ddad4fde8b085ee5c83484c71569830900960
[INFO] [2019-09-30 13:38:21,730 +0530] - 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------- WhiteSource Scan Summary: --------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
======================================================================================================================================================
Scan Origin: Local Docker Images
======================================================================================================================================================
Step                                 Completion Status                              Elapsed                              Comments                              
======================================================================================================================================================
Fetch Configuration                     COMPLETED                                 00:00:00.079                           --------
Scan Files Matching Includes Pattern    COMPLETED                                 00:00:04.918                   399 source/binary files
   dll                                  COMPLETED                                   --------                     399 source/binary files
Docker Resolver Scan                    COMPLETED                                 00:00:13.080                           --------
   image-tag-sha256                     COMPLETED                                 00:00:13.080                   registry.abcd/dataconnector-V.1.0.0.0-7afaac1a588a
      alpine                            COMPLETED                                   --------                     50 packages
Check Policies                          COMPLETED                                 00:00:07.971                           --------
Update Inventory                        COMPLETED                                 00:00:01.151                   1 updated projects


[Pipeline] { (Send Email)
[Pipeline] emailext
Sending email to: 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I am expecting the below line in email body via email-ext.

Project name: registry.abcd/dataconnector V.1.0.0.0 (7afaac1a588a), URL: https://app-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/Wss/WSS.html#!project;id=295252

Comment: Have you tried changing regex="^Project name:" to regex="Project name:"    -   Remove the caret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if you post your code portion where you're calling emailext. The below example works for me as expected, where I've got a process that prints hostnames after the string "Hostname" to the build log.

Email Extension Plugin v2.66

```
    stage('Email the results') {
        emailext attachLog: true,
            attachmentsPattern: '*',
            to: "Me@Somewhere.com",
            subject: "Result: ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
            body: '''
Body
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Hostname", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}

'''
    }
```

Solution for your code, remove the caret ^

```
stage('Send Email') { 
   emailext body: '''Hi, Please find below. ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Project name:", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true} Regards, DT ''', 
   subject: 'Test - Build ${BUILD_STATUS} - Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}', to: 'justin.xavier@abcd.com' 
}
```

Next question on getting rid of everything before "Project name:" - Everything in parenthesis represents "$1", and we'll replace the line with the contents of "$1" using **substText="$1"**

```
stage('Send Email') { 
   emailext body: '''Hi, Please find below. ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex=".*(Project name:.*)", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true, substText="$1"} Regards, DT ''', 
   subject: 'Test - Build ${BUILD_STATUS} - Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}', to: 'justin.xavier@abcd.com' 
}
```

Comment: Please find the code portion below:

`stage('Send Email'){
    emailext body: '''Hi,

Please find below.
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^Project name:", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=10, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}

Regards,
DT
''', subject: 'Test - Build ${BUILD_STATUS} - Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}', to: 'justin.xavier@abcd.com'
}`

Comment: Code `${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Project name:", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=0, maxMatches=5, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}`  

      **I was able to achieve the expected result, however is there a way to remove the portion before 'Project name'?**


`Hi,

Please find below result.
[INFO] [2019-09-30 23:32:33,457 +0530] - Project name: registry.cybertech.com/dataconnector V.1.0.0.0 (7afaac1a588a), URL: https://app-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/Wss/WSS.html#!project;id=2


Regards
DT`

Comment: Thanks for the response though, just wanna fine tune the regex

Comment: To be more specific, i want only "Project name: registry.cybertech.com/dataconnector V.1.0.0.0 (7afaac1a588a), URL: https://app-eu.whitesourcesoftware.com/Wss/WSS.html#!project;id=2" to be shown in email.

Comment: Hey @justinxa tried provided solution for my issue but i am getting "Error evaluating token: Error processing tokens" , I am trying to extract following line from log "OPERATION=backup|ENV_NAME=http://example.com:8091|EVENT=backup|START_TIME=2022-11-10 09:20:28.897461|END_TIME=2022-11-10 09:20:30.824839|RESULT=SUCCESS
"